# Is it possible to offset the window position by a value when WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"?

Tags: c#, wpf

The requirement used to be that the window is `CenterScreen` but the client has recently asked that the window is now slightly to the right of its current position.

The current definition of the window is:

I was hoping that doing the following would work:

```
    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // change the position after the component is initialized
        this.Left = this.Left + this.Width;
    }
```

But the window is still in the same position when it appears on screen.

Do I need to change the startup location to `Manual` and position it myself? If so, how do I get it offset from the center?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handle `Loaded` event, and put `this.Left = this.Left + this.Width;` there:

```
public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyWindow_Loaded);
    }


 void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Left = this.Left + this.Width;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

In the designer
right click on the window
select Properties.
in the properties side panel look for "`StartPosition`"
Set its value to "`CenterScreen`".

Or 
You can try the follwoing code in InitializeComponent() of the window

```
this.StartPosition=FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

Or
if it is a popup window, then try using the below code.

```
this.StartPosition=FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```

Or 
if it is the window from which the application starts with then use the follwoing setting.

```
this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
```